# how to stop rails server (redmine) ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

i've installed and running redmine in my domain. something went wrong and i cant access redmine admin panel. i tried to reset password and also did some google and changed password in database. but no luck still cant login. then i removed all app files but its still running same as before..

this was the code i used to run redmine server

```
bundle exec ruby script/rails server webrick -e -s production
```

now i'm trying to stop or restart but nothing is working.

is there any way to stop the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ctrl+c does not work?

Comment: @nathanvda it's running in online cpanel. so ctrl+c doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill the process

```
kill -INT $(cat tmp/pids/server.pid)
```

Its cleaner to write a rake task to do that:

```
task :stopserver do
  pid_file = 'tmp/pids/server.pid'
  if File.file?(pid_file)
    print "Shutting down WEBrick\n"
    pid = File.read(pid_file).to_i
    Process.kill "INT", pid
  end
  File.file?(pid_file) && File.delete(pid_file)
end
```

Comment: i got this error 

"cat: tmp/pids/server.pid: No such file or directory
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
"

actually, app is running on shared hosting and i dont have sudo auth. last time when i contact hosting support they told me to add "-s" or something similar to keep it running in background.

Comment: can you try `killall -9 rails`?

Comment: got " rails: no process killed " on killall -9 rails

Comment: ok 1 more thing. What output you get for `ps -ef | grep rails` ?

Comment: 'damaroja 21174     1  0 Mar10 ?        00:07:42 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/mongrel_rails start -p 12006 -d -e development -P log/mongrel.pid
krozero  25873 15874  0 11:23 pts/3    00:00:00 grep rails
duany    30580     1  0 Mar18 ?        00:14:20 ruby script/rails server webrick -e production -d
'

Comment: breaking in lines "line 1: damaroja 21174     1  0 Mar10 ?        00:07:42 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/mongrel_rails start -p 12006 -d -e development -P log/mongrel.pid
"

Comment: line 2: krozero  25873 15874  0 11:23 pts/3    00:00:00 grep rails

Comment: line 3: duany    30580     1  0 Mar18 ?        00:14:20 ruby script/rails server webrick -e production -d

Comment: krozero is my username

Comment: `21174` is the process id for rails. You need to figure out a way to kill it. Try `kill -INT 21174`. If that didnt work, ask your hosting providers how to kill a process if you know the process id.

Comment: -bash: kill: (21174) - Operation not permitted . i think i should call support team now. thanks for the help @shivam

Answer (score 1):

Delete the file  `tmp/pids/server.pid)` and then restart the server.

Comment: i don't have sudo access to delete that file and i'm using shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'll hit Ctrl-C to stop webrick when it's started without `-d` option. The `Ctrl-C` makes `INT` signal, so youcould try with `kill -INT <pid>` to stop webrick started with `-d` option.

If it doesn't stop you can try with `kill -9 <pid>` sending a `KILL` signal, that's not a proper clean shutdown but seems the only way to stop it. It's not a 'best practice' but it's the only method i've ever found.

Comment: how can i get pid for the app server? currently it's running on port 3000

Comment: @krozero you could try lsof -i :3000

Comment: it returns nothing. is that mean nothing running in port :3000 ? but my app is still running in :3000

Comment: @krozero are you on the same user that started the webrick server? You can see only your own processes

Answer (score -1):

```
$ killall -9 ruby
```

this command wil kill all the running instance of ruby on your system and you can restart ur server again